# For which real numbers $c$ is there a straight line that intersects the curve $y = x^4 + 9x^3 + c x^2 + 9x + 4$ in four distinct points?

Tags: calculus, contest-math, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

> For which real numbers $c$ is there a straight line that intersects the curve $y = x^4 + 9x^3 + c x^2 + 9x + 4$ in four distinct points?

I don't quite the understand the solution which is in terms of taking the second derivative. Can some one explain it? 
Here is the link to the solution: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asdas/imo/putnam/psoln/psol948.html

Comment: If there are two distinct points of inflection, a line through those intersects the curve four times. Just saying. There could be other solutions.

Comment: I improved your formatting so that it uses MathJax. You should consider making an edit to tag it more specifically, so that users can find it more easily.

Comment: Looked at the solution, evidently I got it right. Wow. I'm a good boy.